# colorbar using values that aren't in a mapping

Tags: numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a figure with multiple subplots.  For each subplot, I'm setting the `facecolor`.  I want to provide a colorbar on the left that gives the face colors I've set context.  However, the only way I've figured out how to do this, includes a `mapping` that I don't want there.

Also, I recognize that this may be an XY question.  I'm open to criticism and any methods to get to my final goal

### [MCVE]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np

np.random.seed([3, 1415])

a = np.random.rand(3, 3)

f, axes = plt.subplots(3, 4)

jet = cm.jet

for i in range(3):
    for j in range(1, 4):
        axes[i, j].set_facecolor(jet(a[i, j-1]))

m = plt.subplot2grid(axes.shape, (0, 0), rowspan=3).imshow(a, jet)
plt.colorbar(m)
```

[image]

I want this

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A colorbar needs to use some mapping between numbers and colors. However if you do not want to show that inside your figure, you may create this mapping in the most general way, namely using a `ScalarMappable` instance.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np

np.random.seed([3, 1415])

a = np.random.rand(3, 3)

f, axes = plt.subplots(3, 3)

jet = cm.jet

for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        axes[i, j].set_facecolor(jet(a[i, j]))

m = cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=jet)
m.set_array([])
plt.colorbar(m, ax=axes)

plt.show()
```

[image]

If a normalization is in the game, e.g. `norm = plt.Normalize(-1,2)`, you'd use it to get the correct colors as `jet(norm(a[i, j]))` and create the mappable as
`cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=jet, norm=norm)`.

Comment: The line `plt.colorbar(m, ax=axes)` is producing the error `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get_figure'`.  Might this be a version issue?  My `np` is `'1.13.1'`, `mpl` is `'2.0.2'`, Python `3.6`.

Comment: Yes, I can reproduce the error in matplotlib 2.0.2. The code works fine in version 2.2.2. If you cannot update your matplotlib, you would need to convert the array of axes to a list, `plt.colorbar(m, ax=axes.flatten().tolist())`.

Comment: Upgraded and fixed.